# Include an angular template in another using webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I have an issue using angular and webpack. My project is composed of multiples views with controllers.

For example, I have a view `userSummary.tmpl.html` which load the list of all users. I would like to reuse this template in another `groupSummary.tmpl.html` which display all users too.

I can't use ng-include because all my views are contained in a bundle.js, nothing else. I would like to use WebPack to include my views directly in another.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why using webpack when you can go for routing and nested views? Take a look here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Thanks @Mikey . I use  the ui-router plugin but it seems to doesn't work in my case. I already use a template in my state and I'm not able to add a view with an ui-view in the html.

Comment: Odd. Works everytime for me. What you want is nested views or not?

Comment: You can use `ng-include` when using something like `ngtemplate-loader` or `ng-cache-loader`, I've worked out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack: using require for ng-include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436729/webpack-using-require-for-ng-include)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable you must to configure the "relativeTo" parameter, otherwise your template partials get loaded at "/home/username/path/to/project/path/to/template/" (Check your bundle.js you're probably leaking your username in your projects)

```js
var ngTemplateLoader = (
    'ngtemplate?relativeTo=' + path.resolve(__dirname, './src/') +
    '!html'
);

module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.html$/, loader: ngTemplateLoader},
        ],
    },
    ...
}
```

Then in your code, do a side-effect only require:

```js
// src/webapp/admin/js/foo.js
require('../../templates/path/to/template.html');
```

Then you can load the html:

```html
<div ng-include src="'/webapp/templates/path/to/template.html'"</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm gonna try that. Thanks

Comment: @DonovanCharpin if this works you can select this as the approved answer.

Comment: If this uses a specific loader (as it seems), it would be nice to give a link (and a NPM name) to this loader...

Comment: It's ngtemplate. webpack automatically appends "-loader" to get the NPM name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-include` when using something like [ngtemplate-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngtemplate-loader) or [ng-cache-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-cache-loader). This will bundle it all into the file, as you mentioned.

Although you can also separate stuff out into separate files with [file-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader) which will clone the file in the bundle directory and supply you paths to each HTML file and will work just the same in angular.

Comment: I'm using ngtemplate-loader but it's not triggering on ng-include at all

Comment: You must use it outside the angular component, else it won't include. Was that really worth a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

In Webpack.config file you can add main html like below

```
   plugins: [ 
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.html'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
    ],
```

Include html-loader in package.json and use the below method in config block alone is enough.

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    template: require('html-loader!root/app/Common/templates/role.html'),
    controller: 'roleController'
})
```

So all the partials will be bundled within the bundle.js itself.No need to add the loaders in webpack-config as well

Comment: Please don't post [identical](http://stackoverflow.com/a/45511348) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/45511404) to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Answer (score 0):

Updtaed the config for 
**Webpack 3**

```
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      { loader: 'ngtemplate-loader?relativeTo=' + __dirname + '/app' },
      { loader: 'html-loader' }
    ]
  },
```

The html can then be imported by using a require in your component js file.

`require('../../templates/path/to/template.html');`

and in your components html file

`<ng-include src="'/webapp/templates/path/to/template.html'"></ng-include>`