# How can you compile angular templates with webpack?

Tags: angularjs, templates, webpack

The idea is to have 1 JS file out of all html files.
and after just to use it via require:

```
templateUrl: require('./views/user-list.html')
```

Could you share you experience please?
I was googling for it and found several loaders for webpack but not sure what to use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I decided to use ng-cache loader for webpack together with ES2015 syntax: it means `import from` instead of `require`.

Part of my webpack config:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', include: APP },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'ng-cache?prefix=[dir]/[dir]' },
    ]
  },
```

and example of directive with template:

```
import avatarTemplate from './views/avatar.html';

const avatar = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      user: '='
    },
    template: avatarTemplate
  }
};

export default avatar;
```

Comment: can you add only a specific folder on the prefix?

Comment: how is this better/worse in your opinion than using require? (curious)

Answer (score 3):

your answer is right. However just offering alternative for it:

```
const avatar = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      user: '='
    },
    template: require("../path/to/file.html"),
  }
};

export default avatar;
```

Comment: how is this better/worse in your opinion than using import? (curious)

Answer (score -1):

In Webpack.config file you can add main html like below

```
 plugins: [ 
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.html'
}),
new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
```

],
Include html-loader in package.json and use the below method in config block alone is enough.

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        template: require('html-loader!root/app/Common/templates/role.html'),
        controller: 'roleController'
    })
```

So all the partials will be bundled within the bundle.js itself.No need to add the loaders in webpack-config as well