# Webpack: using require for ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, angularjs-ng-include

I'm new to webpack and right now I'm using it for the first time in one of my angular projects.

I want to use the require function in my html file in order to require the template for an ng-include like so:

```
<div ng-include="require(./my-template.html)"></div>
```

I know there are loaders like ng-cache and ngtemplate, but they do not work the way I need it. With them, I have to require the template in an js first and than use the template name in my html file.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Create a directive is the simplest way. You can then require in the directive - otherwise look for a loader

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605266/include-an-angular-template-in-another-using-webpack

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [webpack-required-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/required-loader) on npm.

In your app js or module js add comment:

```
//@require "./**/*.html"
```

And in your template you can use

```
<div ng-include="'my-template.html'"></div>
```

Ngtemplate will works fine. Ng-cache works too.

Also note that there is no need for a relative path in the `ng-include` directive because that is taken care of by adding the `//@require` command at the head of your entry file.

Lastly, note that you have to use double and single quotes to get ng-include to work. So you'd do `"'template-name.html'"`, not `"template-name.html"`, or `'template-name.html'`.

[How config loaders](https://github.com/shanhaichik/webpack-require-loader/blob/master/ANGULAR.md)

Comment: How did you setup the loaders?

Comment: @ave, Hi.
In my last project I use this config:

**Webpack config**
`loaders: ['ng-annotate','babel','required?import[]=angular']`

**In app**
`import angular from 'angular';

...
//@require "./components/**/index.js"
//@require "./views/**/*.html"
...
angular.module('sep', requiresModules)
       .config(onConfig)
       .run(onRun);`

Comment: @ave , if there are any questions or suggestions you have. Write [here](https://github.com/shanhaichik/webpack-require-loader/issues), I'll try to answer it.

Comment: thanks for your great answer. but why you not update your answer with -Ave question and put it in comments? :)

Comment: @MojtabaPourmirzaei, hi. Add link, how config loaders :)

Comment: Seems to be out of date with newer webpack errors like: use must use require-loader not just require.

Comment: Hi, @davidbuttar! I do not understand you

Comment: In your docs you say things like 'loader: "ng-cache"' but when I run that it says something like breaking change you must include -loader e.g.  'loader: "ng-cache-loader"' so assuming this helper is out of date. I'm avoiding ng-include now, so don't need this but thought I mention it.

Answer (score 26):

Another approach would be to transform `my-template.html` into a [angular component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component):
Assuming you use [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader) to load your HTML files (`loaders: {test: /\.html/, loader: 'html'}`), define a component `myTemplate` in your module JavaScript file:

```
import myTemplate from './my-template.html';
angular.module(...)
  .component('myTemplate', {template: myTemplate})
```

Afterwards use it:

```
<my-template></my-template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! IMO and for my use case, simplier than the other answers :)

Comment: It is good response however it is not answering the question: What about the ng-include condition?

Answer (score 22):

You can use HTML loader and angular $templateCache service

```
angular
    .module('template',[])
    .run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
        var url = 'views/common/navigation.html';
        $templateCache.put(url, require(url));
    }]);
```

webpack loader config:

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'html',
    query: {
        root:sourceRoot
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works and it is simple, without additional loader (well html loader is pretty standard, I mean). For the record, it also works with the raw loader, according to the configuration found in https://github.com/preboot/angular-webpack To be tested (dev / prod) for other configs if the included fragment references images.

Comment: For the record, I made a variant of the above project at https://github.com/PhiLhoSoft/Angular-Webpack-Playground where I added ng-include as you show.

Answer (score 3):

I've already posted this on https://stackoverflow.com/a/34815472/833093 but:

To enable you must to configure the "relativeTo" parameter, otherwise your template partials get loaded at "/home/username/path/to/project/path/to/template/" (Check your bundle.js you're probably leaking your username in your projects)

```js
var ngTemplateLoader = (
    'ngtemplate?relativeTo=' + path.resolve(__dirname, './src/') +
    '!html'
);

module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.html$/, loader: ngTemplateLoader},
        ],
    },
    ...
}
```

Then in your code, do a side-effect only require:

```js
// src/webapp/admin/js/foo.js
require('../../templates/path/to/template.html');
```

Then you can load the html:

```html
<div ng-include src="'/webapp/templates/path/to/template.html'"</div>
```