# Including html files using ngInclude

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angularjs-ng-include, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-3

I'm trying to include an html file in to another html using ng-include. Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436729/webpack-using-require-for-ng-include) with no luck, maybe due to webpack version differences.

404 errors trying to find the file in the ng-include

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    ..//other dependencies
    "required-loader": "^1.3.15",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    ..//other dependencies
}
```

index.js (entry point to app)

```
import angular from 'angular'
import uirouter from 'angular-ui-router'
import routes from './routes'

//trying to require all files inside views/all dir/all html files
//@require "../views/**/*.html"

angular.module('app', [uirouter])
  .config(routes)
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function() {})
```

index.html file that needs to include navbar.html file

```
index.html
views
 --> common
     --> navbar.html
```

index.html

```
<div ng-include="'navbar.html'">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a better approach to solving this problem instead of using ng-include. I created an angular component for navbar and injected that in to html.

```
<navbar></navbar>
```

in the component definition, I use import statement to call the html template

```
import navbarTemplate from '../PATH';

angular.module('app')
    .component('navbar', {
        template: navbarTemplate,
        ...
});
```

Comment: This is a much better approach in general and a pattern you'll appreciate as you move to Angular in the future. I'm not sure what the empty div tags do, but they may not be necessary. In the outer component/app simply style the navbar element as needed.

Comment: true. it makes the code future proof and easily testable and maintainable as well.