# How to include html partials with webpack (version 2) with the html-loader?

Tags: javascript, webpack, include, require, partials

I am working hard to include a simple footer.html, as an html partial) via `html-loader`. I am using `webpack` version 2.

I failed trying to use `${require('**./footer.html**')}` and `${require('**../footer.html**')}`.

I am not using ejs loader and I do not use the handlebar plugin.

Does somebody know how I can fix this problem and whether it possible to render partials with `webpack`.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: What kind of failure do you see? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: It just printed the ${require('./footer.html')} markup without doing anything. Perhaps it is not possible to render partials with the html-loader, isn't it? If I use the standard loader (might be ejs) than I get an result but this throws an error with the file type .html

Comment: What does "printed" mean? Printed where?

Comment: @Mathias, did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is called [interpolation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#interpolation). Here `{ test: /\.html$/, use: ['html-loader?interpolate'] },` is a webpack configuration *rule* that leverages it by specifying the `interpolate` flag.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solution works fine now. 
Can now simple load Partials with  ${require('./snippets/footer.html')}

Great advice!

Comment: How do you include css or scss for that partial file only?

Answer (score 3):

I use `html-loader` and simply add 
`<%= require('html-loader!./partial/header.html') %>`
to my main `index.html`. Thats work for me.

Comment: Unfortunately it does't render the the require state. It just return  `<%= require('html-loader!./partial/header.html') %>`

Comment: Do you have "html-loader" and "html-webpack-plugin"? Also you can check my webpack config https://github.com/bolten08/webpack/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I already have the plugins in the webpack.config. Do I have to create the partial over HtmlWebpackPlugin, too? Here my webpack https://gitlab.com/redsleeve/webpack

Answer (score 0):

In Webpack.config file you can add main html like below

```
   plugins: [ 
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'index.html'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
],
```

Include html-loader in package.json and use the below method in config block alone is enough.

```
  $stateProvider.state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            template: require('html-loader!root/app/Common/templates/role.html'),
            controller: 'roleController'
        })
```

So all the partials will be bundled within the bundle.js itself.No need to add the loaders in webpack-config as well

Answer (score 0):

I tested with you webpack.config.js file. All you have to do is to **remove** the following from it:

```js
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: ['html-loader']
},
```

So that the [fallback lodash loader comes into play](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md#1-dont-set-any-loader).