# Included partial in Webpack 4 rendering as literal text instead of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I'm trying to include a header.html in my index.html, as a partial via [html-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#interpolation) but header.html is rendering as literal text instead of HTML. Using interpolate as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374187/how-can-i-provide-parameters-for-webpack-html-loader-interpolation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768351/how-to-include-html-partials-with-webpack-version-2-with-the-html-loader) seems applicable to Webpack v2. I also noticed that the #interpolate hash in [html-loader URL](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#interpolation) is not working; meaning interpolate is defunct as of Webpack v4? Webpack emits an error about an *Invalid options object* if I include options: `{ interpolate: true }`

**Tree**

```
--dist
--node_modules
--src
----js
------index.js
----partials
------header.html
--templates
----index.html
--package.json
--webpack.config.json
```

**webpack.config.json**

```
const path                  = require("path"),
    webpack                 = require('webpack'),
    { CleanWebpackPlugin }  = require("clean-webpack-plugin"),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin       = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
   mode: "development",
   entry: {
       index: "./src/js/index.js"
   },
   plugins: [
       // new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist/*']) for < v2 versions of CleanWebpackPlugin
       new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
       new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
           title: "Home",
           filename: "index.html",
           template: "templates/index.html",
           inject: true,
           minify: true
       })
   ],
   devtool: "source-map",
   devServer: {
       contentBase: "./dist"
   },
   output: {
       // filename: "[name].bundle.js",
       filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
       // publicPath: "/"
   },
   optimization: {
       moduleIds: "hashed",
       runtimeChunk: "single",
       splitChunks: {
           cacheGroups: {
               vendor: {
                   test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                   name: "vendors",
                   chunks: "all",
               }
            }
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                loader: "html-loader",
                options: {
                   minimize: true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= require("html-loader!./src/partials/header.html") %>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1**

So I figured that `interpolate` doesn't work in v1.0.0 of `html-loader` basis [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527619/how-to-include-raw-static-html-file-into-another-html-file-with-webpack)

My next question would be what alternatives do I have in place of `interpolate` in v1.0.0?

Comment: What is `<%= ... %>` in your code?

Comment: What about installing v1.1.0 of `html-loader` ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV I ended up downgrading to v0.5.5. The partial is pulling but somehow webpack injects `module.exports = "<header>...</header>"` I don't know why

Comment: @connexo `<%= require("html-loader!../partials/_header.html") %>`

Comment: I've never seen this syntax `<%= ... %>`. That is neither a valie HTML comment, nor a valid tag, nor anything valid by the looks of it.

Comment: @connexo I'm certain `<%= ... %>` are valid templating tags. We've a live site running on Webpack v2 using `html-loader` v0.5.5 and `html-webpack-plugin` v3.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded `html-loader` to v0.5.5 because `interpolate` option wasn't working with `html-loader` v1.0.0. Also, I changed **index.html** to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= require("html-loader!../src/partials/header.ejs") %>
    </body>
</html>
```

The path in the initial `<%= require(...) %>` was wrong. I wonder if that was typo. I also changed the partial from a .html to .ejs (The implementation that's live had partials in the .html format for `html-webpack-plugin` v3.2.0, which I downgraded to but still didn't work. I've no clue why it didn't work)

I also took the liberty to upgrate `html-loader` to v1.1.0 as suggested by @IVO GELOV so that my **package.json** looked like this:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "csv-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
    "xml-loader": "^1.2.1"
},
```

And, interpolate worked. Not sure what's wrong with `html-loader` v1.0.0

Comment: Since `html-loader:v1.0.0` interpolation is not working anymore and was replaced by preprocessor:
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#preprocessor